# Subleading Double soft theorms for photons

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics

I found in the literature that there are double soft theorems for gravitons and gluons both at the leading and sub-leading level. Also double soft limit has been derived for non linear sigma models and Einstein Maxwell theories. But I no where found a double soft theorem for photons (At the leading and sub-leading level). I found papers about the double soft limit by Cachazo et al and Double Soft limits for gravity and gluons by Nandan et al.

Is there any special reason why there is no double soft limit for photons (eg:scalar QED theory)? I am specially interested in the sub-leading case.